# JavaScript sort array of objects on multiple properties by specific constant values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

Given an object like:

```js
accounts = [
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "USD", amount: 123.45 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "CAD", amount: 1.95 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "USD", amount: 23.31 },
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "CAD", amount: 1953.1 },
];
```

How do I sort by the objects properties in the array where `bankType` of `"Checkings"` are sorted first then `currency` of `"CAD"` accounts are sorted next to achieve the following result below?

```js
// Sorted array of objects result
[
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "CAD", amount: 1953.1 },
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "USD", amount: 123.45 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "CAD", amount: 1.95 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "USD", amount: 23.31 },
];
```

The problem isn't about sorting it alphabetically using the built-in [*`localeCompare`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function, the problem lies in having to sort by specific constant value of `Checking` first then by `CAD` second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a point system

```
Checking = 2

CAD = 1
```

```js
console.log(
    [
        { bankType: "Checking", currency: "USD", amount: 123.45 },
        { bankType: "Saving", currency: "CAD", amount: 1.95 },
        { bankType: "Saving", currency: "USD", amount: 23.31 },
        { bankType: "Checking", currency: "CAD", amount: 1953.1 },
    ]
        .sort((a, b) => {
            const pointsA = (a.bankType === "Checking" ? 2 : 0) + (a.currency === "CAD" ? 1 : 0);
            const pointsB = (b.bankType === "Checking" ? 2 : 0) + (b.currency === "CAD" ? 1 : 0);

            return pointsB - pointsA;
        })
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just compare the two in order:

```js
accounts.sort((a, b) =>
    a.bankType.localeCompare(b.bankType) || a.currency.localeCompare(b.currency)
);
```

Comment: added clarity to the problem. my problem isn't being able to sort alphabetically by `localeCompare`, but by a constant value of `Checking` first then `CAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.sort` and `String.prototype.localeCompare`, you can sort them.

```js
const accounts = [
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "USD", amount: 123.45 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "CAD", amount: 1.95 },
  { bankType: "Saving", currency: "USD", amount: 23.31 },
  { bankType: "Checking", currency: "CAD", amount: 1953.1 },
];

const output = accounts.sort((a, b) => {
  const bankCompare = a.bankType.localeCompare(b.bankType);
  if (bankCompare === 0) {
    return a.currency.localeCompare(b.currency);
  }
  return bankCompare;
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, added clarity to the problem. My problem isn't being able to sort alphabetically by `localeCompare`, but by a constant value of `Checking` first then `CAD`.